# Can I determine what event triggered an event handler in jQuery if I bind multiple ones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Check this example:

```
$('button').bind('click focus', function() {

   // Did I click or focus?
});
```

Is there a way to work that out when binding multiple events to one handler?

This *may* work, but it is kind of ugly:

```
var eventType;

$('button').click(function() {
   eventType = 'click';
   do();
});

$('button').focus(function() {
   eventType = 'focus';
   do();
});

function do() {
    alert(eventType);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`event.type`](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/) on the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) (the first param passed to the handler), like this:

```
$('button').bind('click focus', function(e) {
  if(e.type == "click") {
    //do something, it was a click
  }
});
```